# network structure --- k-cliques vs p-cliques

Tags: graph-theory, network

In network structure, what is the difference between **k-cliques** and **p-cliques**, can anyone give a brief explaination with examples? Thanks in advanced!

============================

EDIT:
I found an online [ppt](http://open.umich.edu/sites/default/files/SI508-F08-Week7-Lab6.ppt) while I am googling, please take a look on **p.37** and **p.39**, can you comment on them?

Comment: Where did you run across the notation? Google returns only 1090 hits for "k-clique" "p-clique". Without further context, generally speaking, a $k$-clique is a complete graph on $k$ vertices, and a $p$-clique is a complete graph on $p$ vertices. There is no difference other than the variable name.

Comment: please see the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curiously, in the linked document, neither $n$-cliques nor $p$-cliques mean what mathematicians would consider to be their definitions.

> Mathematical definition: An *$n$-clique* is a complete subgraph on $n$ vertices ([Wikipedia ref.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_%28graph_theory%29)).  [And a $p$-clique is an $n$-clique with $n$ replaced by $p$.]

The linked document instead uses the definitions:

> An *$n$-clique*, where $n$ is a positive integer, is a collection $C$ of vertices in which any two vertices $u,v \in C$ have [distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_%28graph_theory%29) $\leq n$.
>
> A *$p$-clique*, where $p$ is a real number between $0$ and $1$, is a collection $C$ of vertices in which any vertex has $\geq p |C|$ neighbors in $C$.

Essentially, the definition is used to identifying clique-like ways of finding dense clusters in networks.

Personally, I would avoid both of these definitions, since both $n$-cliques and $p$-cliques (according to these definitions) might not be cliques.